# Defining global variable in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

**Model: Comment.php**

```
class Comment extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'comments';
    public $timestamps = true;
}
```

**Controller: PageController.php**

```
class PageController extends BaseController {
    $top_comments = Comment::take(3)->get();
    return View::make('page', array('top_comments' => $top_comments));
}
```

**View: page.blade.php**

```
@foreach ($top_comments as $comment)
    user #{{ $comment->user_id }}:<br />
    {{ $comment->comment}}
@endforeach
```

This works perfect with the `page.blade.php` view which I can define as a route (`/page`). However, I can't seem to figure out how to achieve this globally.

Example: I want to be able to use the `@foreach` containing `$top_comments` in my `master.blade.php` file. Right now if I was to use the above, it works great on `/page` but not on `/`, `/about`, `/tos`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `View::share('top_comments', Comment::take(3)->get());` to make it available everywhere. Of course, you'll have to place it some place where it gets loaded no matter what page you load if you want it in every possible view. (One such place would be in the `__construct()` method of your `BaseController`, but I doubt that could be considered a best practice. Not sure where I'd put it myself.)

Another way would be to leverage view composers, like this:

```
View::composer('master', function($view)
{
    $view->with('top_comments', Comment::take(3)->get());
});
```

This works if you meant that you want it in your `master.blade.php` no matter from where it is loaded, because it's bound to that view. If you choose this option, I recommend for instance creating a file `composers.php` and including that in `app/start/global.php`.

That said, I assume your controller sample above left something out, because it looks like it's missing a method declaration.

Comment: Put it in your routes file, filters file or create an `app/composers.php` file and load by adding `require app_path().'/composers.php';` to your `app/start/global.php` file.